# While cycle and inputs

Tags: c#

I have code like this, how can i add 4 more inputs? (5 in total) and program would return the square of them(num*num, dont know how i should be in english, maybe correct?) Thank you very much for your time!

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication9
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number to get square");
                int num = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                int ruut = num * num;
                while (num!=1000)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(ruut);
                    break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you offer some example inputs and their corresponding outputs?

Comment: What's going on with that 1000 in your code? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: If you input 5 numbers the program would return the square value of all 5 of them. Square(algebra function).

Comment: Program just stops when input is 1000, just for practice, nothing to do with function :D

Comment: So are you just asking how to take your input in a loop?

Comment: 5 inputs to be accurate

Comment: Have you learned about loops yet? `for` is your friend here; since you know the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

use a `for` loop and an array.  Here's an example in the simplest code possible:

```
int[] num = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    num[i] = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num[i] * num[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have used "for" for it But thank you for your time! :)